# Need Help in TabBar Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

please help me a little in TabBar android

i m using a TabBar the code is below

```
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0">
        </TabWidget>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Now my Tab Bar displays on the whole screen .. 
what i want is that on the top right corner i want to display 2 small images and then it should display a tab bar. on the other part of the screen.. please help me guide how do i add into it..

Thnks a bunch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow [this example](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/res/layout/tabs.xml#L10), with replacing the TextView on Line10 with your image view(s).